# IP address agreement

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, ip-address

I'm rather new to networking, so I have a question about setting up IP addresses with their subnets. The IP addresses I am working with are:

192.168.135.1 255.255.255.0 - host

208.184.124.50 255.255.255.252 - router

192.168.42.2 255.255.255.0 - backup router

These IPs are all connected to different ports on my ASA5505. want to know if these addresses would have trouble communicating with each other. I am inclined to think the answer is yes because the second subnet is different from the rest, but I am not sure. Any thoughts/feedback on this would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: All three networks are different. It depends on the firewall rules you have in place, but you can route between different networks. That is how networking works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention how the subnets are connected, but if you have a router(s) connecting the subnets, then any subnet should be able to communicate with any other (assuming nothing peculiar is going on).  There is nothing special about IP addresses that make them "troublesome."  The fact that some subnets are "numerically similar" to others makes no difference to the router.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I edited the question to include information about how everything is connected.

Comment: As I said, there's nothing inherently wrong with the addresses.  The policies on the ASA may restrict how the different subnets can communicate.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. I guess I will have to look elsewhere in the configuration to solve my problem.

Comment: You can post a new question with your actual problem and we can try to help you with it.  Be sure to include the ASA configuration.

Comment: I actually posted one last week that went unanswered, here's the link to it: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33092/isp-failover-phone-registration-loss